# How to count number of Agents in a multi Agent System Using JADE Framework?

Tags: java, excel, agent, agents-jade

I am new to JADE and I need to write some information about my multi agent system in an excel file, including the number of agents in a multi agent system, can any body help me how to find the number of agents in a MAS?

Firstly I Run the project with a certain number of agents, e.g. 50. But when agents' job is done I need one of the agents to write the number of all agents in an excel file.

---

Edited:

I have another question, how can I change the number of agents in a multi agent system so that it can reorganize itself again and start from setup method again

Comment: you can use "yellow pages service". Every you agent must register itself with `DFService.register` and you will be able to find them all with `DFService.search`.

Comment: or you can try AMSService.search(Agent a, AMSAgentDescription amsd)